# IS their any type of software like notepad wherein I can put images in it

Tags: notepad

I just wanted some program like notedpad which can store image as well as text in it. I know I can do this by using MS Word also. But notepad is faster, more responsive than MS Word. Can any one suggests some softwares or ideas to do this.

Comment: Are you looking for a text editor that can also handle images(never seen one), or are you asking for any character manipulation program that will also work with pictures but is more responsive than word?

Comment: @ a sandwhich =I am looking for a text editor that can also handle images. Yes I also haven't seen this type of editors but it can be possible that some one might be knowing about this.

Answer (score 0):

How about WordPad? It comes free with Windows (type Wordpad in the start-menu search or look in C:\Windows\system32\wordpad.exe)